# Lista de 3 posições. Cada uma contém uma lista de duas posições ambas inteiros. Ordenar pelo maior inteiro da 2ª posição

Tags: python-3.x

```
listaSupermercados1 = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [1, 15]]
def comprarBananas(listaSupermercados):
    listaSupermercados.append(listaSupermercados)
    comprimentoLista = len(listaSupermercados) -1
    posicao = 0
    posica1 = 1
    posicaoSubsequente = posica1 + 1
    listaOrganizada = []
    while posicao < (comprimentoLista):
        valorUnitarioPosicaoInicial = listaSupermercados[posicao][posica1]
        valorUnitarioPosicaoSubsequente = listaSupermercados1[posicaoSubsequente][posica1]
        if valorUnitarioPosicaoInicial < valorUnitarioPosicaoSubsequente:
            listaOrganizada.append(listaSupermercados[posicao])
        else:
            listaOrganizada.append(listaSupermercados[posicaoSubsequente])
        posicao += 1
        posicaoSubsequente = + 1
    print(listaOrganizada)

comprarBananas(listaSupermercados1)
```

Cada sublista tem 2 posições com inteiros e desejo criar uma nova lista em ordem crescente pelo valor de cada elemento na 2ª posição das sublistas
Mas recebo o erro:

> ERROR: if valorUnitarioPosicaoInicial < valorUnitarioPosicaoSubsequente:
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: BAH nem sequer postar direito eu consigo :-(

Comment: Seu código não está apresentando erro, mas não está fazendo o que deveria. De uma forma pythônica, você poderia fazer algo como: `sorted(listaSupermercados1, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: Oi Paulo Obrigado! Não consegui entender o seu código (sou novo em Python) Poderia explicar como eu coloco ele no meu código?

Comment: Consegui ! Muito Obrigado

Comment: listaSupermercados1 = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [1, 15]]

def comprarBananas(listaSupermercados):
    listaOrganizada = sorted(listaSupermercados, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(listaOrganizada)



comprarBananas(listaSupermercados1)